# How to populate subsequent data with data from the first row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data set that I have created from a few sub-queries that needs to keep track of the an amount financed and an amount charged off.

Current Data:

```
QuarterDiff   ActivationYear   ActivationQuarter   AmountFinanced   ChargeOffAmount
0             2015             1                   83831.00         19600.00
1             2015             1                   NULL             0.00
2             2015             1                   NULL             0.00
3             2015             1                   NULL             0.00
4             2015             1                   NULL             0.00
```

The issue that I am running into is the following data for `AmountFinanced` should not be `NULL`, but repeat the `QuarterDiff` 0 `AmountFinanced` value. Is there a way to have the value from `QuarterDiff` 0's `AmountFinanced` populate into the following `QuarterDiff`s?

Desired Result (for `ActivationYear` 2015, `ActivationQuarter` 1):

```
QuarterDiff   ActivationYear   ActivationQuarter   AmountFinanced   ChargeOffAmount
0             2015             1                   83831.00         19600.00
1             2015             1                   83831.00         0.00
2             2015             1                   83831.00         0.00
3             2015             1                   83831.00         0.00
4             2015             1                   83831.00         0.00
```

Comment: Are you familiar with calculated field in SQL? Add a calculated field in the table and read off the value from there.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution for this problem is to use a subquery for the *AmountFinanced* column, like this

```
select  QuarterDiff,
        ActivationYear,
        ActivationQuarter,
        (select AmountFinanced
            from Finance_Table
            where QuarterDiff = 0
        ) as AmountFinanced,
        ChargeOffAmount
    from Finance_Table
```

This only works for what you want if the quarter and activation year don't change, because then you know the QuarterDiff that you should use to populate AmountFinanced, namely, QuarterDiff 0.

A harder problem you may face involves multiple years and quarters, such as this table.

```
QuarterDiff   ActivationYear   ActivationQuarter   AmountFinanced   ChargeOffAmount
0             2015             1                   83831.00         19600.00
1             2015             1                   NULL             0.00
2             2015             1                   NULL             0.00
3             2015             2                   76931.00         0.00
4             2015             2                   NULL             0.00
5             2015             3                   101263.00        0.00
6             2015             3                   NULL             0.00
7             2015             3                   NULL             0.00
8             2015             4                   99754.00         0.00
9             2016             1                   69414.00         0.00
10            2016             2                   88200.00         0.00
11            2016             2                   NULL             0.00
12            2016             2                   NULL             0.00
13            2016             2                   NULL             0.00
```

This one is not as easy because you can't just pick QuarterDiff 0 to populate the rest of your table. You want to pick the AmountFinanced from the leading record for a given Year and Quarter. Instead, we can use aggregates of correlated subqueries, which takes advantage of the data in the AmountFinanced field; that is, the ones that need to be populated are null, so they don't interfere with any aggregation.

```
select  QuarterDiff,
        ActivationYear,
        ActivationQuarter,
        (select max(AmountFinanced) -- or sum
            from Finance_Table ftsq
            where ftsq.ActivationYear = ft.ActivationYear
                and ftsq.ActivationQuarter = ft.ActivationQuarter
        ) as AmountFinanced,
        ChargeOffAmount
    from Finance_Table ft
```

To better understand why this works, let's consider the block of records where ActivationYear = 2015 and ActivationQuarter = 3. Then, the subquery becomes

```
select max(AmountFinanced)
    from Finance_Table ftsq
    where ftsq.ActivationYear = 2015
        and ftsq.ActivationQuarter = 3
```

So the subquery pulls out a section of the table, apples the aggregate over that section, which for this example results in 101263.00, and applies that result to the AmountFinanced column. Since we use variables instead of the numbers 2015 and 3, it is able to do it correctly for every record in the table.

*As a side note, a safer way to do this would be to use ranking, which is robust regardless of the data found in the AmountFinanced column. But you probably have enough to chew on for now.